# Abstracting patterns in induction rule for inductive predicates for Coq

Tags: coq

Consider the following proposition in Coq:

```
Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
 | nil_s : forall (l: list nat), subseq nil l 
 | cons_in l1 l2 x (H: subseq l1 l2) : subseq (x :: l1) (x :: l2)
 | cons_nin l1 l2 x (H: subseq l1 l2) : subseq l1 (x :: l2)
.

Lemma subseq_remove_rewritten: forall (x:nat) (l1' l1 l2 : list nat),
  subseq l1' l2 ->
  l1' = (x :: l1) ->
  subseq l1 l2.
Proof. 
  intros x l1' l1 l2 H1 H2.
  induction H1.
  - discriminate.
  - injection H2 as H3 H4.
    rewrite H4 in H1.
    apply cons_nin. apply H1.
  - apply IHsubseq in H2.
    apply cons_nin. apply H2.
Qed.

Lemma subseq_remove: forall (x:nat) (l1 l2 : list nat),
  subseq (x :: l1) l2 ->
  subseq l1 l2.
Proof. 
  intros x l1 l2 H. 
  apply subseq_remove_rewritten with (x:=x) (l1':=x :: l1).
  apply H.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I worked in Isabelle before Coq. There originally, the induction tactic could not solve directly this goal and the trick was to come up with a lemma like subseq_remove_rewritten and then prove the original goal. This is the situation in the manual Isabelle/HOL: A Proof Assistant for Higher-Order Logic. Later, the tactic became smarter and one can write patterns in which to abstract on. So the proof is written like this:

```
lemma 
  assumes "subseq (x # l1) l2"
  shows "subseq l1 l2"
  using assms
  apply(induction "x # l1" "l2" rule: subseq.induct)
    apply simp
   apply(intro subseq.intros(3),simp)
  by (intro subseq.intros(3))
```

I was wondering if Coq has a similar way to avoid proving a lemma like subseq_remove_rewritten and go directly to prove subseq_remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dependent induction` tactic (documented [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.dependent-induction)).  For example:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import Coq.Program.Equality. (* Needed to use the tactic *)

Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
 | nil_s : forall (l: list nat), subseq nil l
 | cons_in l1 l2 x (H: subseq l1 l2) : subseq (x :: l1) (x :: l2)
 | cons_nin l1 l2 x (H: subseq l1 l2) : subseq l1 (x :: l2)
.

Lemma subseq_remove: forall (x:nat) (l1 l2 : list nat),
  subseq (x :: l1) l2 ->
  subseq l1 l2.
Proof.
  intros x l1 l2 H.
  dependent induction H generalizing x.
  - now apply cons_nin.
  - eauto using cons_nin.
Qed.
```

Unfortunately, though this tactic has been around for a while, it is still described as experimental in the reference manual, and I don't know if the Coq developers have any plans of improving it in the future. It has a few deficiencies, such as not allowing the user to name the variables and hypotheses used in the induction proof. I personally prefer to add the equality assumptions to the proof myself, as in your first attempt, or to reformulate the definition of `subseq` as a `Fixpoint`, so that you can invert the hypothesis by simplification.  For example:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint subseq (l1 l2 : list nat) : Prop :=
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _ => True
  | x1 :: l1, [] => False
  | x1 :: l1, x2 :: l2 => x1 = x2 /\ subseq l1 l2 \/ subseq (x1 :: l1) l2
  end.

Lemma subseq_nin x2 l1 l2 : subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l1 (x2 :: l2).
Proof. destruct l1 as [|x1 l1]; simpl; eauto. Qed.

Lemma subseq_remove: forall (x:nat) (l1 l2 : list nat),
  subseq (x :: l1) l2 ->
  subseq l1 l2.
Proof.
  intros x l1 l2 H.
  induction l2 as [|x2 l2 IH]; try easy.
  destruct H as [[<- H]|H]; eauto using subseq_nin.
Qed.
```